# Jenkins: Is it possible to scan specific pull request in Jenkins from github actions?

Tags: git, jenkins, github, cloudbees, github-actions

I have a github actions yaml file as follows:

```
name: Trigger Jenkins after PR is approved
on: 
    pull_request_review:
      types: [submitted]
jobs:
    triggerJenkins:
        name: Trigger Jenkins
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            -   name: trigger
                run: curl -X POST https://githubUsername:${{secrets.JenkinsToken}}@cloudbees.xyz.com/teams/job/repositoryName/job/jenkinsJobName/build
```

So when the PR is approved, then jenkins job is triggered and it scans the repository and runs all the opened pull requests (PR) together. But I want to trigger specific pull request from Jenkins. To make you more clear what I want to do here is explained with the help of short example:

I have created a new Pull request and its URL is: https://github.com/xyz/repositoryname/pull/2500

Whenever this pull request is approved, it triggers Jenkins job from github actions and Jenkins starts scanning all pull requests together. So if there are 10 pull requests opened in github for xyz repository then all 10 pull requests checks are started in jenkins. But I only want to trigger this pull request which I just created it with PR number 2500.

However this issue can be resolved if I use webhooks, but I don't want to use that. I only want to trigger specific pull request to jenkins job when it is approved from github actions. I don't want to scan the whole repository from jenkins and run all the PR checks in jenkins job.

On this image shown below you can see that it is scanning all PRs triggered by github actions. So if somebody can look into this issue and provide me the solution will be great help.
Thanks

[image]